# Is there any similar filter concept of twitter finagle in play framework

Tags: scala, playframework

In twitter's finagle, there is a filter concept, they can be composed and applied on service to add function to the service, like adding timeout or retry, the concept and example can be find here: http://twitter.github.io/finagle/guide/ServicesAndFilters.html

In playframework, you call a 3rd party service like this:

```
WS.url(requestUrl).get
```

The network is unstable, one of the solution is to add retry mechanism, when get failed, we can resend the url to retry.

We know how to add a retry for this case, I just want to know whether there is similar filter concept in playframework, so you can combined them and add new functionality to WS calling.

Answer (score -1):

Out of the box in Play there are no such filters. You can however add them yourself using Action composition as described on the [official documentation.](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaActionsComposition)

Comment: Thanks, I know action composition, but they are different thing. But how to do WS calling composition?